# Storage behaviour in ReentrancyGuardUpgradable

Tags: storage

I'm working on the UUPS upgradable proxy pattern and need to implement the `ReentrancyGuard` to my contract. While I was checking the contract code, I found the storage declaration is a little bit different from the ordinal apporach.

```
    // keccak256(abi.encode(uint256(keccak256("openzeppelin.storage.ReentrancyGuard")) - 1)) & ~bytes32(uint256(0xff))
    bytes32 private constant ReentrancyGuardStorageLocation = 0xff....ff;


    function _getReentrancyGuardStorage() private pure 
        returns (ReentrancyGuardStorage storage $) {
        assembly {
            $.slot := ReentrancyGuardStorageLocation
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know the reason?